# about searching by using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

This is the structure of my class ContentItem

```
@interface ContentItem : NSObject {
    //properties of this class
    NSString *name;
    NSString *type;
...
}
```

an NSArray has above class's objects.
I want to search the objects by searching words.
So I tried to do this.

```
NSArray *filteredItem = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchString]];
```

result:

```
Can't use in/contains operator with collection 
        <ContentItem: 0x68309b0> (not a collection)
```

Actually I don't know how to search the objects.
Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to access the property you are intending to search on. See the Apple docs for [Using Predicates with Key-Paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-250409)

e.g.

```
NSArray *filteredItem = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF.name contains[cd] %@", searchString]];
```

for both properties

```
NSArray *filteredItem = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF.name contains[cd] %@ OR SELF.type contains[cd] %@", searchString, searchString]];
```

Comment: Paul.s // Then is it possible to search not only 'name' but all properties at once?

Comment: Hopefully some one can give a better solution but you can just extend the predicate with another condition. See updated answer.

Comment: @StanPak See also `- (NSPredicate *)predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:(NSDictionary *)variables` so you don't have to repeat 'searchString'